# How to correctly use a variable in Event Handler functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to resize div elements using javascript .
I have this code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>home page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapCSS/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="column1" class="column">left</div>
        <div id="column2" class="column">middle</div>
        <div id="column3" class="column">right</div>
        <script>
            var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");
            var displaysize = window.innerWidth;

            window.onresize = function () {
                for (const column of columns) {
                    if (window.innerWidth < 560) {
                        column.style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else {
                        column.style.display = "inline-block";
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

> Scripts here are working correctly, But when using **displaysize** variable in the if statement the function is not working.
>   So, what is the problem with this code.

**Edit**

Even this is not working when function is named like function resizer(),then calling on the event

Comment: The if statement won't work with displaysize because since displaysize is instanciate before the onresize func, it will never be re-instanciate. It will always have the same value, check this fiddle to better undestand : https://jsfiddle.net/javtdyfe/

Comment: @abvlle but this is also not working after naming the function like resizer(), please explain

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is that, as @abvlee said, your `displaysize` value was instanciate out of the event handler. Then, the value won't be changed when the function is called. Move it to inside the handler and you'll see it work.

```js
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName("column");

window.onresize = function() {
    var displaysize = window.innerWidth;
    for (const column of columns) {
    
       if (displaysize < 560) {
          column.style.display = "block";
       } else {
          column.style.display = "inline-block";
       }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>home page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrapCSS/bootstrap.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="column1" class="column">left</div>
    <div id="column2" class="column">middle</div>
    <div id="column3" class="column">right</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `displaysize` variable is not being reassigned the new window value on window resize because it is outside the scope of the function.

### Solution 1

```
<script>
  var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
  var columnArrayLength = columns.length;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var displaysize = window.innerWidth;

    for (var i = 0; i < columnArrayLength; i++) {
      if (displaysize < 560) {
        column.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        column.style.display = "inline-block";
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

While this fixes the problem of the `displaysize` being out of scope it isn't quite what you asked so I have the next solution.

### Solution 2

```
<script>
  var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column');
  var displaysize = window.innerWidth;
  var columnArrayLength = columns.length;

  window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    displaysize = window.innerWidth;

    for (var i = 0; i < columnArrayLength; i++) {
      if (displaysize < 560) {
        column.style.display = "block";
      } else {
        column.style.display = "inline-block";
      }
    }
  });
</script>
```

This solution is what you asked for, `displaysize` is defined outside of the function then a new value is reassigned to it when the window resize fires.

## But wait there's more!

You could just use a media query in your css instead of using javascript.

```
.column {
  display: block;
}

@media(min-width: 560px) {
  .column {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

This is the best solution and doesn't rely on javascript!